# Check if string is in string literal type

Tags: python, types, typing, typechecking

We use static type checking extensively, but we also need some simple runtime type checking. I'd love to use our static types for that runtime type checking. I've seen typeguard and the other libraries, but I'd prefer to have something simpler.

I've tried below, but `assert value in expected_type` doesn't make sense. How do I create a simple function that will check if a string is in a Python string literal?

```
from typing_extensions import Literal

def check_str_in_literal(value: str, expected_type: Literal):
    assert value in expected_type

Gender = Literal["Male", "Female", "Other"]
def print_gender(gender: Gender):
    print(gender)

# Unknown string as it's been retrieved from elsewhere
strRetrievedFromDB = "Male"  # type: ignore

check_str_in_literal(strRetrievedFromDB, Gender)
print_gender(strRetrievedFromDB)
```

Comment: `typing` has extremely little runtime support. Something designed for runtime use, like `enum`, may be more suitable for your use case.

Comment: Okay, how would you do it with `enum`?

Comment: Have a `Gender` enum with `Male` and `Female` values, (attempt to) retrieve the enum value for a string when the strings enter your code (and catch the failure if the string is invalid), and pass enum values around internally instead of strings.

Comment: (While we're talking about gender values, it might be appropriate for this field to have some kind of "missing" or "other" option.)

Comment: True. Bad example on my part :/

Comment: @pir I believe the question could be closed. Please select answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Python 3.8 introduced [`typing.get_args(tp)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args), making this possible:

```py
assert value in get_args(expected_type)
```

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the content of a `Literal`, we can see that the values are inside the private attribute `__args__`

```py
>>> from typing_extensions import Literal
>>> literal = Literal["a", "b", "c"]
>>> literal.__dict__
{'_inst': True,
 '_name': None,
 '__origin__': typing.Literal,
 '__slots__': None,
 '__args__': ('a', 'b', 'c'),
 '__parameters__': (),
 '__module__': 'typing'}
```

Therefore, one way if really need to use `Literal` is to do as such:

```py
def check_str_in_literal(value: str, expected_type: Literal):
    assert value in expected_type.__args__
```

However, it's usually not a good idea to use private attributes.

As mentioned in comments, you could also used `Enum` (or other type of enums from `enum` module), as such:

```py
import enum
from typing import Optional

class Gender(enum.Enum):
    Male = enum.auto()
    Female = enum.auto()
    Other = enum.auto()

def get_gender(gender:str) -> Optional[Gender]:
    """Get an Enum Gender from its name (None if not valid)"""
    try:
        return Gender[gender]
    except KeyError:
        return None

def print_gender(gender:Gender) -> None:
    """Do something with a gender"""
    print(gender.name)


gender_from_db = "Male"
gender = get_gender(gender_from_db)
if gender:
    print_gender(gender)
```

Comment: No need "to use private attributes" thanks to `from typing import get_args`: `assert value in get_args(expected_type)`.

Comment: @JosephMarinier Nice addition: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args ... although it is only introduced in Python 3.8.  I will update my answer later (or feel free to do so yourself if you like).

Comment: Oh I see! I'll write a new answer then. Merci! 